# React-native - iOS device crashes "undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, crash, runtime-error

The app runs fine on the emulator and all Android devices. When I try to run on an iOS device the app opens and then crashes almost instantly. I can't seem to locate the issue as s.Manager is not mentioned anywhere in my code.

What I have done:

- Deleted node_modules, updated some, reinstalled
- Deleted pod files, updated pods, reinstalled

Error logs:

```
2019-12-04 17:11:40.958445+0100 mid[9239:4992389] undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')
2019-12-04 17:11:40.964 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')
2019-12-04 17:11:40.963688+0100 app[9239:4992383] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')
2019-12-04 17:11:40.964 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-12-04 17:11:40.964345+0100 app[9239:4992389] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-12-04 17:11:41.179884+0100 mid[9239:4992383] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager'), stack:
u@80:391
<unknown>@80:1029
forEach@<null>:<null>
<unknown>@80:1015
h@2:1670
<unknown>@79:49
h@2:1670
```

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   app                                 0x000000010202490b RCTFormatError + 0
    3   app                                 0x0000000102046bbc -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 495
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb138c __invoking___ + 140
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bae49f -[NSInvocation invoke] + 319
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bae9a4 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68
    7   app                                 0x0000000102058a20 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 578
    8   app                                 0x000000010205acce _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 246
    9   app                                 0x000000010205aa56 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516ac810 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516ad781 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516b34ee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516b3f24 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff516bdffc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff518cd611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff518cd3fd start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

dependencies

```
   "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.2.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "base64-js": "^1.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.0.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.1.0",
    "metro-config": "^0.55.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-devtools-core": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-native-action-sheet-component": "MY_PACKAGE",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-auth0": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^2.11.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-deep-link": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.5.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.5",
    "react-native-flags": "MY_PACKAGE",
    "react-native-fs": "2.15.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "MY_PACKAGE",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^0.6.6",
    "react-native-modal-filter-picker": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-phone-input": "MY_PACKAGE",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-pincode": "MY_PACKAGE",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.16",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "^10.9.0"
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any external library? And also is this an expo project or cli project?

Comment: Yes, I use many external libraries. The error message is so vague and doesn't point me in any direction as to which library could be causing this.
It is a cli project.

Comment: delete iOS/build and run it again.

Comment: I think there is some library which is causing issues with android.. run all the steps you did and also run react native link to link all librarirs. If that didnt work then look at libraries you have added latest and try removing them and then running them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that running the following command fixes the issue.

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```